# Override return value in event handler?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm sure this has been asked before, but I haven't had any luck finding an answer. There's probably a term for this which I don't know.

Can a jQuery event handler return an element other than the one from which it was triggered?

Normally, when you trigger a jQuery event for an element, that element will be returned by the event handler. Is there a way to return a different element instead? (other than `event.target`, `event.currentTarget`, etc.)

Here's my HTML:

```
<div id="content">
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div class="instance">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

If I make a custom jQuery event for `#wrapper`, can I make its event handler return an `.instance`?

Here's my JavaScript:

```js
$('#content').on('new.instance', '#wrapper', function(event) {
    var wrapper = $(event.currentTarget);
    var instance = wrapper.find('div.instance').first();

    var newInstance = instance.clone(true, true);
    newInstance.appendTo(wrapper);

    return newInstance;
});

var returnValue = $('#wrapper').trigger('new.instance');
console.log('returnValue.html():', returnValue.html()); // #wrapper, not .instance
```

Can I make the `new.instance` event handler return an `.instance` element? If so, what am I missing in the code?

Comment: This setup will not work, event handlers don't return values (at least not in this way) and `$(...).on(...)` is going to return a jQuery collection, not the return value of the callback. Can you not perform the necessary work within the event handler?

Comment: Yes, since `.instance` is on the event.chain being that it's on the same path when in `bubblingPhase`. What exactly would you expect from `.instance`? You can get `.instance` as e.target.

Comment: I was basically trying to see if I could use a jQuery event as a constructor. I've been hoisting the new `.instance` out of the function but it'd be a lot cleaner if I could get it from a return value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [**.trigger()**](https://api.jquery.com/trigger/)
>
> *...*
> *When we define a custom event type using the .on() method, the second argument to .trigger() can become useful.*

You could simply add an object to the `.trigger` method as a second parameter and collect your instances in there.

```js
var instances = {data:[]};

$('#content').on('new.instance', '#wrapper', function(event, instances) {
  var wrapper = $(event.currentTarget);
  var instance = wrapper.find('div.instance').first();
  var newInstance = instance.clone(true, true);
  instances.data.push(newInstance);
  newInstance.appendTo(wrapper);
});

$('#wrapper').trigger('new.instance', instances);

console.log(instances.data[0].get(0));

// somewhere else at a latter time trigger new.instance again
setTimeout(function() {
  $('#wrapper').trigger('new.instance', instances);
  $.each(instances.data, function(index, item) {
    var counter = index + 1
    item.text( 'cloned instance ' + counter );
    console.log(item.get(0))
  })
}, 2000)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content">
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div class="instance"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`.instance` is in the `event.chain` so you can access it on callback during the `bubbling phase`. Review the Snippet by clicking each element.

Snippet

```js
var wrp = document.getElementById('wrapper');

wrp.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if (e.target != e.currentTarget) {
    var trueTarget = e.target.className;
    alert(trueTarget + ' has been clicked!');
  }
  e.stopPropagation();
}, false);
```

```css
#content {
  border: 2px dashed grey;
  width: 50vw;
  height: 50vh;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  text-align: right;
  color: white;
}
#wrapper {
  border: 3px dotted orange;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  text-align: right;
  font-size: small;
  color: orange;
}
.instance {
  border: 1px solid yellow;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
  text-align: center;
  font-size: smaller;
  color: yellow;
  
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  CONTENT
  <div id="wrapper">
    WRAPPER
    <div class="instance">
      INSTANCE
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```